# Access Calculated Fields

Tags: ms-access-2010

I have a table in Access 2010 as below

```
Customer Country  Quantity  Multi
1        DE          5       y
2        DE          5       n
3        DE         10       y
4        DE          5       n
5        FR          5       n
6        FR         10       y
7        FR          5       y
8        FR         10       n
9        UK          5       n
10       UK          5       n
11       UK         10       y
12       UK          5       y
```

I created a standard report and set a grouping around country.  In the country header I want a calculated field   counting the number of compnanies for which Multi = "y".  But when I type =Count([Multi]='y') it only counts the total records in the group.  It won't take the subtotal where multi= 'y'.  I have no idea what is going wrong.

Comment: Showing a result table would really us understand what you want. So please do :)

Comment: Sorry, it's not a table. It's a calculated control in a report form. In a report form I group by country and then in the Country Header place a text box with the formula =Count([Multi]='y').  I have seen this work elsewhere but in my report it only counts the total number of records in the group. not the subtotal of "Multi=y"